# Ansible ec2_metric_alarm region issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-cloudwatch

```
- name: Create Alarm
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    region: us-west-2
    name: "Low_On_CPU"
    metric: "CPUUtilization"
    namespace: "AWS/EC2"
    statistic: Average
    comparison: ">="
    threshold: 75.0
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 1
    unit: "Percent"
    description: "The alarm will send notification message when CPU is over 75 percent"
    alarm_actions: "{{ alarm_action }}"
    ok_actions: "{{ ok_action }}"
```

For the regions: I wanted to apply the cloud alarm for us-west-2 but I got an error. Which said:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,   "msg": "BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request\nhttp://monitoring.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-08-01/\">\n  \n    Sender\n    `ValidationError`\n    Invalid region us-east-1 specified. Only us-west-2 is supported.\n  \n  fca09709-ad15-11e6-89f8-c1737af27609\n\n"}

When I tried the same with us-east-1 and it worked but doesn't work with any other regions except us-east-1. I tried the same with us-east-2, us-west-1, us-west-2 but no luck. Any suggestions about how to work around this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible, but to what endpoint are you sending the request? To add a metric for us-west-2, you probably have to send the API request to us-west-2. This is normally configured in the software that is making the connection to AWS.

Comment: ansible has its own modules using which it makes API calls. It uses boto.ec2.cloudwatch to create alarms.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The code has no problem. Refer the real module codes (https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/amazon/ec2_metric_alarm.py#L272-L278), it is simple and works. So if you do have issue, please raise a ticket to https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core as bug report.

Comment: Did a further check, maybe it is a bug. There is no `connect_to_aws` module in `boto.ec2.cloudwatch`, it should be changed to `connect_to_region`. http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region . Report to ansible is the best way to follow it up. Or if you can fix it, raise pull request directly

Comment: What are your `alarm_action` and `ok_action`? I think your SNS topic is in `us-east-1` but the alarm is in `us-west-2`. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes! You are right. It is the sns topic causing the script to fail. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Clarify the answer in the comments from helloV.

The issue is that the SNS topic for alarm_actions is in a different region to where the alarm is being created.